# xv6 boot loader memory range

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, xv6

From book-rev8(DRAFT as of September 3, 2014 Page 95), it says:

**"The boot loader itself is at `0x7c00 through 0x7d00`"**, but `0x7d00 - 0x7c00` is `256 bytes`, not `512 byes`(The BIOS reads `512 bytes` from disk).

So, I think the boot loader itself is at `0x7c00 through 0x7e00`, but I'm not sure whether I'm right.

Comment: BIOS can read one sector, but bootloader code may occupy only 256 bytes, what is the problem with that? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @AlexHoppus I know that the bootloader may occupy less than 512 bytes, I mean whether the 512 bytes of memory is **reserved** for bootloader no matter how much memory the bootloader occupies, that’s to say, the modern operating system will never use the unused memory of the 512 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS reads block 0 of the HD into the 512 bytes begining at address 0x07C00.

Like the Terminator, this is what it does.